# Estoy intentando pasar de Ilist<Empleado> a list<Empleado>

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando pasar de Ilist a list para luego mostrarlo en un DataGridView pero me sale error... me dice que no es posible convertir implicitamente

```
List<Empleado> lista = new List<Empleado>();
lista = servicio.Consultar();
```

Comment: Para poder determinar el problema, debemos saber el error y la sección de código con el que estás trabajando, así como está la pregunta es posible que se cierre por ser demasiado amplia o porque no está claro lo que se pregunta

Comment: Consultar es de tipo Ilist?

Comment: Qué tipo de datos devuelve servicio.Consultar(); y de qué tipo de datos está compuesta la lista. Ejemplo: List<Coche> lista = new List<Coche>()

Comment: La lista esta compuesta por -> Saldo, nombre y apellido del empleado @ManuelNicolás

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas,
El asunto es que IList<> es una Interfaz, en cambio List<> es una clase, IList expone unos métodos públicos que la clase List implementa. 
Para solucionar tu problema, tienes tres opciones, hacer que el método devuelva una List, o que la variable donde lo recibes sea IList, o pasarle la Interfaz en el constructor

```
IList<Empleado> lista;
lista = servicio.Consultar();

List<Empleado> lista = new List<Empleado>(servicio.Consultar());
```

Atte

Comment: Si se puede, pasando el interface en el consturctor, ya he corregido, que se me habia pasado esa opcion, tienes toda la razon

Answer (score 4):

Utiliza el metodo extensor [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) sobre el tipo `IList<Empleado>`:

```
List<Empleado> empleados = servicio.Consultar().ToList();
```

[`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx) implementa [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) por lo que tiene disponibles todos los metodos extensores de `System.Linq.Enumerable`,  entre ellos esta el metodo `List<T> ToList(this IEnumerable<T> source)` que convierte un `IEnumerable<T>` a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es hacer crear la nueva lista pasándole al constructor el `IList` que te devuelve tu método `servicio.Consultar()`:

```
List<Empleado> lista = new List<Empleado>(servicio.Consultar());
```

Comment: @sstan como siempre,tienes toda la razón del mundo. No es un cast, sino  la creación de una nueva lista. Corregido.